# Ren`py -- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'random'

Tags: python, renpy

Делаю ВН на ренпай. Стоит задача сделать transition со случайно выбираемой полутоновой картой. Прописываю в инит собственно сами переходы:

```
$ randtransit_in = ImageDissolve(im.Tile("mods/tests/i/transit/trans[rtin].jpg"), 1, 1, reverse=False)
$ randtransit_out = ImageDissolve(im.Tile("mods/tests/i/transit/trans[rtout].jpg"), 1, 1, reverse=False)
$ random_transition = MultipleTransition([False,randtransit_in, Solid("#000"),randtransit_out,True])
```

Далее объявляю переменные, которым присваивается случайное значение:

```
python:
    rtin = renpy.random.randint(0, 9)
    rtout = renpy.random.randint(10, 19)
```

В итоге происходит краш с ошибкой AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'random'

UPD:
Всё оказалось и проще, и сложнее одновременно. Для работы рандомайзера достаточно вписать его непосредственно в строку с путём к файлу.

```
ImageDissolve(im.Tile("mods/tests/i/transit/trans"+str(random.randint(0,9))+".jpg"), 1, 1, reverse=False)
```

Но теперь проблема в том, что рандомайзер отрабатывает только один раз при загрузке, а надо, чтобы отрабатывал при каждом вызове перехода.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если я правильно понял [документацию](https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/python.html), то, наверно, нужно делать как-то так:

```
init python:
    import random

python:
    rtin = random.randint(0, 9)
    rtout = random.randint(10, 19)
```

Comment: посмотрите и эту документацию https://www.renpy.org/doc/html/other.html    renpy.random.randint(a, b)
Return a random integer such that a <= N <= b.

Comment: @Интик Ну, у меня этой штуки нет под рукой, я чисто гадаю. Возможно, в таком виде как `renpy.random.randint` оно отрабатывает **вне** блока `python:`, но это же надо проверять.